# Как преобразовать элементы списка в двоичный код

Tags: python

Как преобразовать элементы списка в двоичный код?
Язык python 3.7

Comment: Что именно здесь вы понимаете под словами "двоичный код"? Опишите в целом задачу, которую вы решаете.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
l = [1,2,3, [1,5,3], {}]
import base64
print "{:b}".format(int(base64.b16encode(str(l)), 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант.

```
lst = [0, 1, 0, 0]
x = bin(int(''.join(map(str, lst))))
print(x[2:])
```